# Why use a saucer for hydroponics?

Tags: containers, hydroponic

I’m trying to get into some home grown hydroponics, to grow some tomatoes and chilies fresh over the winter (without having to import them). I’ve used a kit before to grow basil and this used one solid container filled with water which needed topping up occasionally.

I’m trying to put together the pieces to replicate this on a larger scale for tomatoes, but I keep seeing saucers and plant pots with drain holes. My question is, why use a saucer with a plant pot filled with water? Will the water not come out of the bottom of the plant pot, into the saucer and overflow out of the saucer?
Should I keep hunting for non draining plant pots?

I’m currently using old mugs, plastic nets and some clay beads grow medium, with the water and nutrients in the mug at the bottom. So really I was hoping to do the same but with an actual plant pot.